# Is it hypothetically possible to create a giant levee that is a non-physical forcefield or electronic membrane?

Tags: technology, physics, chemistry, energy, water

What examples are there in science fiction of molecular shields that can cancel out or "eat" certain molecules--and are they plausible? Is it hypothetically possible to create a giant levee that is a non-physical forcefield or electronic membrane that could cover a greater scope than steel or concrete, such as a thousands-of-miles shoreline in danger of flooding due to a rising sea level? Any examples or instances of this being done on a small scale would be helpful to answer the question.

I'm trying to figure out how much energy would be needed to produce a giant barrier like this. Maybe it can convert the water molecules to energy, too, if they are washing into it at a substantial force.

Comment: You want this to work on and only on "water molecules"?

Comment: Do you mean something like a semi-permeable membrane as those used in [reverse-osmosis water desalination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_osmosis)?

Comment: These answers are great, and thoroughly respond to what's implied in the question--but let me rephrase: would a non-physical forcefield or electronic membrane make sense as a substitute for a steel and concrete dam and as a solution for covering a greater scope, such as thousands of miles of shoreline in danger of flooding due to a rising sea level?

Comment: @AnthonyWorman: You should put everything you just said into your question in order to clear things up and get answers that are more relevant. At the bottom of your question below the list of tags there should be an 'edit' button.

Comment: What do you mean by "eat"?  And why do you want to eat them instead of just block them?

Comment: an electric field doesn't sound like a good idea to be absorbed by water.  Your field would dissipate into the water.  Are you looking for star trek science where force fields block everything somehow and apply a repulsive force?

Comment: *"Maybe it can convert the water molecules to energy, too"* you are aware of E = mc^2, right? This would melt the planetary crust.

Comment: What is a "non-physical forcefield"? Some kind of ESP or magic or the literal Hand of God or something? Sure, if your world has non-physical things that can affect physical things, they can do whatever you want, but then you can't ask for "how much energy", because energy is a physical quantity.

Comment: I'm told that it happened in the Red Sea once.

Answer (score 26):

This very much exists in the real world, on a colossal mind boggling scale.  It is not brand new tech but it is still super useful and still amazing on many levels.  Here is a fine example:

[image: hoover dam]
https://cleantechnica.com/2018/07/26/city-of-los-angeles-wants-to-turn-hoover-dam-into-worlds-largest-pumped-energy-storage-facility/

The Hoover Dam, 8th Wonder of the World.  The molecules involved are those of concrete and steel and they can indeed be switched into and out of place with giant mechanisms.  And as requested, the giant barrier that is the dam does very much convert water molecules into energy.  The cool thing - you extract energy from the water and then still have the water molecules when you are done!

Comment: What a great answer, +1. @ClayDeitas I hope this ping works - I told you that some things are just not implied on WB, this is a perfect example. Sometimes people miss the obvious

Comment: These answers are great, and thoroughly respond to what's in the question--but let me rephrase: would a non-physical forcefield or electronic membrane make sense as a substitute for a steel and concrete dam and as a solution for covering a greater scope, such as thousands of miles of shoreline in danger of flooding due to a rising sea level?

Comment: @AnthonyWorman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_control_in_the_Netherlands

Comment: @Raditz_35 Either the @ has to be the first thing in the comment, or the person has to be in the thread, because I didn't get pinged. However, I ended up here anyways and I see what you mean.

Comment: If you want to ping someone, they must either (a) be the original author of the post being commented on, (b) have edited the post, or (c) have a non-deleted comment on the post. @ClayDeitas (Position doesn't matter, see?)

Comment: @Nic Hartley Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 8):

What you are referring to is not science fiction, it is science fact. Biological science in particular. An example is the fat (lipid) molecule.

> Nonpolar molecules that repel the water molecules are said to be
>   hydrophobic; molecules forming ionic or a hydrogen bond with the water
>   molecule are said to be hydrophilic. This property of water was
>   important for the evolution of life. Hydrophobic interaction plays the
>   most critical roles in the formation of the lipid bilayer of the cell
>   membrane and the folding of proteins and nucleic acids; therefore,
>   hydrophobic interaction is the foundation for the existence of life.

https://www.nnin.org/education-training/k-12-teachers/nanotechnology-curriculum-materials/water-race-hydrophobic-0

You might also want to research soap.

> Washing up liquid is a kind of soap. Normally, oil and water don't
>   mix, so they separate into two different layers. Soap breaks up the
>   oil into smaller drops, which can mix with the water. It works because
>   soap is made up of molecules with two very different ends. One end of
>   soap molecules love water - they are hydrophilic. The other end of
>   soap molecues hate water - they are hydrophobic

from http://www.planet-science.com/categories/under-11s/chemistry-chaos/2011/06/soap---how-does-it-get-things-clean.aspx

However, it is not yet scaled up to the size you want. But doing so is just a matter of economics and the availability of capital to do so. It would 'just' take a lot of engineering and the blending of engineering with biology.

But unfortunately, the bottom line is that no matter how hydrophobic the molecule, you are faced with the mechanical problem of holding back the pressure from the water. That is, it is not difficult to make a huge barrier of hydrophobic molecules, but it would just be swept away by the force of the water. How do you reinforce and anchor the membrane? Somehow, you would need a huge counter-pressure. Say, a very highly pressurized bubble, perhaps?

But then, it is not the hydrophobic qualities that are holding back the water, it is the mechanical properties of the structure that contains the hydrophobic molecules.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the question as it is now, a sort of solid energy barrier to block water, you would need a cold plasma shaped by magnetic fields to act like a barrier.

Plasma is just ionized gas, such as evaporating wax as it's burning at the top of a candle. It's quite easy to control the flow of plasmas within electromagnetic fields.

To ionize something, either add electrons or strip away electrons.  A high voltage antenna such as a tesla coil can ionize air quite easily, making spectacular arcs of lightning fly out. The process goes on in fluorescent light bulbs, neon signs, all TVs except for the LED based ones, etc., and as I said earlier, from many chemical reactions that cause things to burn.

What is beyond the realm of physics, though, is a way to keep a gas ionized while it's in contact with water.  Since non-purified water is an excellent conductor, as soon as a plasma touches it, the plasma is grounded out, bringing the number of electrons back to a neutral state.

Since your gas is in a neutral state, it's not a plasma any more, so can't be directed by magnetic fields.

This is where you'd use some handwavium: a gas that stays ionized even when in contact with an excellent conductor.

Alternatively, you could keep on bombarding the seas with newly ionized plasmas accelerated towards the water by vast arrays of plasma "guns" (which would resemble a gun in much the way a wide nozzle power washer resembles a gun; it's not a single kinetic round travelling in a ballistic arc, it's a steady stream of particles spraying out and expanding out in the same general direction) but then it's the wind pushing the water back, not any sort of "energy barrier."  You might as well just get tons of fans to blow the water; as it would be far more efficient and just as hilarious.

If you want to avoid handwavium, though, just set up [inflatable dams](http://www.imcbrokers.com/blog/overview/detail/storm-surge-barrier-quot-balgstuw-quot) like they have protecting some inland lakes from storm surges in the Netherlands.

Comment: I love the image of the Netherlands with a wall of giant high-speed fans along the coast. Might be dangerous for fishing boats, but might be even more hilarious than dangerous.

Comment: @abarnert That is by far the best answer here and yet it's only a comment.

Comment: @ClayDeitas The image comes straight out of Ghedipunk's answer, all I added was the fishing boats. I would love someone to turn his throwaway idea into a real answer—work out how powerful the fans would have to be, how much of the Netherlands would have to be covered in windmills to power them, and how fishermen could possibly dock anywhere. But that's beyond my estimation abilities.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question, this is a short and sweet one:

**What you are asking for doesn't exist using any known science - therefore there is no known plausible or hypothetically possible way to do it.**

... There may well be ways to solve the problem that *are* physically possible though if you are able to ask another question defining your requirements or you can just do what other similar sci-fi does and hand-wave the force fields into existence by assuming some scientific breakthrough. If you do that you can give them whatever properties you need.

Comment: You're not answering OP's question: _"What examples are there **in science fiction** of molecular shields that can cancel out or "eat" certain molecules--and are they **plausible**?"_

Comment: @Flater "There's nothing plausible about this," is a valid answer to the question.

Comment: @Frostfyre: The issue is more that this answer limits itself to _any known science_, which is overly restrictive for a question that explicitly asks about sci-fi examples.

Comment: @Flater ...so, because there could be science we haven't uncovered yet, we can't rule out the possibility of something maybe existing at a future date? How does one reference _unknown_ science to confirm whether something is plausible?

Comment: @Frostfyre: OP is asking for **examples in science fiction**. He's not asking for future predictions of actual science that is currently unknown.

Comment: @Flater The question asks "are they plausible". The answer is no - there is no plausible known mechanism by which to create force fields as depicted in science fiction. I hope that this will change at some point but it will need some very significant breakthroughs.

Comment: Note that a question just asking for a list of types of force field in science fiction would almost certainly be off topic. It's only on topic because it asks for more than that.

Comment: @TimB: Your answer explicitly limits itself to known science. Regardless of the plausibility of known science; you're omitted sci-fi examples, which is the explicit scope of the question. I didn't say your answer was wrong (there is indeed no known technology that makes force fields feasible), I said **it doesn't answer OP's question**.

Comment: @Flater The question wants to know if there are examples in fiction and if they are plausible. Tim's answer is that there is no plausible method to achieve this. This answers the question of if any method is plausible without providing examples because every example is based on handwavium and, thus, not plausible.

Comment: @Flater We're just going to have to agree to disagree I think. The OP explicitly asks if they "are plausible" and if they are "hypothetically possible". The answer to both parts is no. I'm not sure why you think that's not an answer.

Comment: @TimB: What you are claiming in the comments is not what is in your answer. Your answer specifies that **it doesn't exist using any known science** which is wholly different from not being plausible. I can agree with what you're saying in the comments but your answer simply doesn't reflect that same stance.

Comment: @Frostfyre, No, Tim's answer is quite literally that **it doesn't exist**, not that it's not plausible.

Comment: @Flater The two facts are related, I've edited the answer though. Hopefully that's clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it hypothetically possible to create a giant levee which can be switched on and off that acts as a “water-molecule negating” shield?

There are at least two **spillways** in Louisiana on the Mississippi River.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonnet_Carr%C3%A9_Spillway

[image]

> The Bonnet Carré Spillway /ˈbɒniː ˈkɛriː/ is a flood control operation in the Lower Mississippi Valley. Located in St. Charles Parish, Louisiana – about 12 miles (19 km) west of New Orleans – it allows floodwaters from the Mississippi River to flow into Lake Pontchartrain and thence into the Gulf of Mexico. The construction of the Spillway was completed in 1931.

Basically, it's **a set of gates in the levee**.  They remain closed except during times of unusually high water during spring floods.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Water is actually effected both by electric charges and by magnetic fields, but either requires such a strong field that you would basically be making a levee out of electromagnets or modified telsa coils and still not blocking the water completely.

https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-a-magnet-attract-water-the-way-a-static-electricity-charged-balloon-does

Answer (score 3):

### Standing Waves

This is where a mechanical device creates vibrations in the water such that a wave is formed, but it interacts with other water movement so as to create a wavetop that doesn't move.

For instance, canals could have "standing wave locks", where instead of gates the standing waves are manipulated to float the boat up.  If the locks we built long, the boat wouldn't even have to slow down.

In flood control, the standing waves would simply keep the water out and up at the top of the wave, which never makes any headway toward shore.

Of course if the power fails, instant tsunami...

Comment: This is a really interesting idea, I am not sure it would work as I see several potential holes in the idea...but it's certainly worth further thought.